# cannot run local mongo server on OSX

Tags: mongodb, macos

Good day,

I used to be able to run mongo server on localhost from the shell with the command `mongod --config /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` but unfortunately now the command silently fails.

if I try `which mongod` I will get `/usr/local/bin/mongod`. I have tried restarting my machine and doing `brew uninstall mongodb` followed by `brew install mongodb` but I get the same effect.

The contents of my config file located at /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf are as follows:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

By the way if I try to run `mongod` without the `--config` option I get the following errors:

```
2016-11-28T11:01:01.288-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=4895 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Danials-MacBook-Pro.local
2016-11-28T11:01:01.289-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.2.11
2016-11-28T11:01:01.289-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 009580ad490190ba33d1c6253ebd8d91808923e4
2016-11-28T11:01:01.289-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
2016-11-28T11:01:01.289-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-11-28T11:01:01.289-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-11-28T11:01:01.289-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-11-28T11:01:01.289-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-11-28T11:01:01.289-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-11-28T11:01:01.289-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-11-28T11:01:01.290-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 29 Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2016-11-28T11:01:01.290-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] dbexit:  rc: 100
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Log file clearly says that the data directory /data/db not found..
Please create the directory for data and start the mongod process.
In your case,the value given to the dbPath in your config file is the data folder.

Comment: I already tried that before, if I create that directory then it will complain that certain files don't exist in the directory. something is missing. Me manually adding folders won't help :(

Comment: Have you tried changing the path instead of  /usr/local/var/mongodb give someother path.

Comment: No I have not, that is just the default